# Export pandas dataframe to excel with rows separated by borders according to a multiindex level

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I have a pandas dataframe with a multi-index, and I would like to export it to excel with a specific style.
My goal is to make it visually clear which rows belong together according to specific levels of the multi-index.

In the following example we have two index levels and one column. The thick borders are determined by the first index level, and the thin borders are determined by the second.

[image: Illustration]

EDIT: Adding the closest thing I could get, which is drawing borders on all the rows in the file.

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    export_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tab_name')       
    workbook = writer.book
    sheet = writer.sheets['tab_name']
    for i in range(export_df.shape[0]):
        sheet.set_row(i,height=None,  cell_format=workbook.add_format({'border': 1}))
    writer.save()
```

I searched for code examples, but couldn't find any for this use case. Is it even possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CharlieClark
I added my best attempt so far, but I don't think there's a way for me to achieve what I want though this functionality, though.

Comment: You need to merge the cells in column A if this doesn't happen already. If Pandas isn't doing what you want, you're best of using xlsxwriter or openpyxl directly. You'll need your own code for the thicker borders but that shouldn't be hard.